# Copy link address from Android/iOS app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hyperlinks, ios-app

Not sure if this actually applies to the iOS app, as I'm an Android user, but I figure both platforms share the same features.

When browsing my favorite SE sites from the Chrome app, I can copy a link's address by tapping & holding - there's some sort of context menu just for that.

It would be nice to enable something like that in the app, so comments, questions, answers and other hyperlinks could be copied and then pasted onto a new comment, question or answer... or into the ChatSEy app, or anywhere I want.

Instead of using the SE app, I often use Chrome to do that. The app already supports tap & hold *paste from clipboard*, why couldn't links be copied from the SE app?

(yes, this is a phone post from the Android app)

---

Update: please read this as a feature request to add some "copy url" functionality for anything that doesn't already have it through the "share" button (comments, user profiles, ...anything else?)

Comment: This is indeed needed for the iOS app, but as they are different dev teams and different codebases, it's recommended to post two separate feature requests.

Answer (score 1):

On the Android app you can currently copy the link to any question or answer by hitting "Share" then selecting "Copy to clipboard", this will copy just the URL of the post to your clipboard.

You can't currently copy URLs to comments, but I don't expect that to be that important. If it is, feel free to change this to a feature-request for just adding that and I'll add it in if others agree.

Comment: this *is* a [meta-tag:feature-request] already ;)

Comment: I copy comment URLs all the time and just switched from my ancient iPhone 4 to a shiny new Moto X, so I'll start the foot tapping now.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm saying remove the other things in it and make it *just* a feature-request for that portion, because as is 2/3rd of this request is already in the app.

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know it was. I was expecting *tap & hold* to be the way to do this on Android... (well in the Chrome app at least)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Using "Share" to copy to clipboard is a common Android paradigm on all Google Play powered devices, it's been [there for a few years](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/29/tip-drives-latest-update-adds-global-copy-to-clipboard-option-in-the-share-menu/).